# OnFlashlight in android

Tags: android, camera

In my android application i am recording video using Media recorder.I would like to on and off the flash as the recording is started and stopped.
Is there anyway that i can achieve it in android.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [FLASH_MODE_TORCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_TORCH).

The whole code may goes like

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Bit i am using mediarecorder.How can i start camera object and set these parameters to media recorder.I am new to android so i am sorry if its silly

Comment: @Remmyabhavan, do you mean: you are using an app but not programming an app?

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting recoding , just call a function

/*
     * Turning On flash
     */
    private void turnOnFlash() {
        if (!isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }
            // play sound
            playSound();

```
        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}
```

and when you click on stop Recording just call Stop Flash Function

Flashlight can be turned off by setting flash mode to FLASH_MODE_OFF.

```
 /*
 * Turning Off flash
 */
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        // play sound
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        // changing button/switch image
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}
```

/*
         * Switch click event to toggle flash on/off
         */
        **btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFlashOn) {
                    // turn off flash
                    turnOffFlash();
                } else {
                    // turn on flash
                    turnOnFlash();
                }
            }
        });**